# Using selectAll() to create new elements while preserving existing elements

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to work through some d3 tutorials so please bear with my noob questions.  As I understand it, in order to create new elements of a certain type, you have to use `.selectAll()` on the non-existing elements and then use `.append()` to create them. That works great when there are no existing elements matching the specified selector, but if there are, it will select that/those elements and append the new elements inside them.  Take this example:

```
d3.json("virusOrigins.json", function(dataset) {
    var w = 200;
    var h = 300;
    var barPadding = 1;
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d.value; })])
                    .rangeRound([5, w])
                    .nice();

    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)

        // append base rectangle
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h)
        .attr("fill", "#ccc");
    svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            return i * (h / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return xScale(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return (h / dataset.length) - barPadding;
        })
        .attr("fill", "#f33")
        .classed("bars", true);
});
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<svg width="200" height="300">
    <rect width="200" height="300" fill="#ccc">
        <rect y="0" x="0" width="13" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="33.333333333333336" x="0" width="5" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="66.66666666666667" x="0" width="5" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="100" x="0" width="5" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="133.33333333333334" x="0" width="5" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="166.66666666666669" x="0" width="200" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="200" x="0" width="5" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="233.33333333333334" x="0" width="5" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
        <rect y="266.6666666666667" x="0" width="5" height="32.333333333333336" fill="#f33" class="bars"></rect>
    </rect>
</svg>
```

How can I get the dynamically created rect's to be siblings of the base rect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saving the `rect` in `svg` and then appending to it. Simply save the `svg` element instead:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

// append base rectangle
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("fill", "#ccc");
svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
// etc
```

Comment: Oh, I see.  By using the chaining, the initial rect became part of that selection.  I thought it would refer to just the svg element itself.

Answer (score 1):

Change your data insert as follows:

```
svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
   .data(dataset, function(d){return d;}) <-- Here *
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   ...
```

- add the function to tell that you want to take into account all data not for the existing elements but really to generate new elements.

For more information, see [example 3](http://knowledgestockpile.blogspot.ch/2012/01/understanding-selectall-data-enter.html) of this article on Understanding selectAll, data, enter, append sequence in D3.js.

Comment: Lars' answer is the one I was looking for, but that was a very informative post.  I haven't gotten that far in my d3 studies yet but I'm sure I would've scratched my head about that one sooner or later.  Thanks.