# Can I use selectAll to create new element when elements of same type already exist?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I want to use two different data sources to add `g` elements to the `svg`. However, I end up binding the second data source to existing `g` elements rather than creating new `g` elements.

Here's an example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var canvas_w = 1280 - 80,
        canvas_h = 800 - 180;

    var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
        .append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", canvas_w)
        .attr("height", canvas_h)   

    var category_cells = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data([0, 1, 2])
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "category")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {console.log(d); return "translate(" + d*100 + ", 0)"; });

    category_cells.append("rect")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .style("fill", "blue");

    var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data([3, 4, 5])
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "cell")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {console.log(d); return "translate(" + d*100 + ", 0)"; });

    cell.append("rect")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", 50)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .style("fill", "black");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This script displays three boxes of class `g.category` instead of six boxes with three of class `g.category` and three of class `g.cell`. It also only logs "1 2 3" showing that the transformation after the `enter` statement for `g.cell` is never entered. Additionally, if I update the transformation at the end of the script by adding

```
svg.selectAll("g.category")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {console.log(d); return "translate(" + d*100 + ", 0)"; });
```

The `g.category` transformation changes to reflect the data `[3 4 5]`. It's clear that the new data is overwriting the `g.category` data rather than being assigned to new `g.cell` elements, but how can I prevent this from happening?

The [tutorials](https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements) and [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) I have read talk about binding data to elements that don't yet exist, but they don't handle the case that elements of the same type already exist.

My guess is that the solution lies somewhere in the update pattern. From the documentation there are several places that I can change the attributes of various elements.

```
var update_sel = svg.selectAll("g").data(data)
update_sel.attr(/* operate on old elements only */)
update_sel.enter().append("g").attr(/* operate on new elements only */)
update_sel.attr(/* operate on old and new elements */)
update_sel.exit().remove() /* complete the enter-update-exit pattern */
```

But it doesn't explain how the `data` call changes the data binding of the old elements.

[Using selectAll() to create new elements while preserving existing elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986269/using-selectall-to-create-new-elements-while-preserving-existing-elements) asks how to use `selectAll` without nesting elements inside of each other which isn't the issue that I am facing.

Comment: Just use `.selectAll("g.category")` and `.selectAll("g.class")` when creating the elements.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This worked for me! I'm still curious about how the data call changes the data binding if you know any details.

Comment: It doesn't, you're simply selecting different sets of elements. In your previous code, you were selecting *all* the `g` elements and binding data to them, with this the selection is restricted to `g` elements of a particular class.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I understand that is the case for when I select `g.category` or `g.cell`, but what is going on under the hood in the original example when I select `g` for the second time and the data in `g.category` changes? Does d3 decide to rebind the first 3 svg elements because the new data provided has three elements? Or does it select the data and svg elements to bind in some other way?

Comment: The default data binding in D3 uses just the index, i.e. the first datum is bound to the first element, the second to the second and so on. Any data that may already be bound to the elements is not considered at all. So when selecting the `g` elements for the second time, you're rebinding the data as you describe.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks. If you would like to make your comments into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by default, D3 uses the index to match data. That is, the first datum matches the first DOM element in the selection, the second the second, and so on. In your code, you're selecting `g` elements in both cases, so for the second time this code is run, data is rebound to the elements and you get a result you don't expect.

The solution is simple -- just select the elements by the classes you've assigned, i.e. use `.selectAll("g.category")` and `.selectAll("g.class")` when creating the elements. Alternatively, you could provide a key function to `.data()` to tell D3 how to match elements and data to prevent the rebinding, but IMHO that would be less intuitive.